# How can I increment a repeating number until 195 on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sequence

How can I have it increment a number that repeats 12 times, so that it looks like this:

```
1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

2

2

2

2

2

2

2

2

2

2

2
```

I've been trying to tweak this formula, but with no success:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(1&",",12), , 999^99), ",")))`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=arrayformula(INT(sequence(12*195,1,0,1)/12)+1)
```

[sequence](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(TEXT(SEQUENCE(12), SEQUENCE(1, 12,,))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(195)/12,0))
```

Comment: Thank you! Had to choose the one below, as it was submitted first. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AntonioSantos As your wish but you should choose answer which is more effective and fast performance (not based on submitted date and time).

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you would like to tweak your original formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(sequence(12)&",",12), , 999^99), ",")))
```